# Why is my async function returning a pending promise after await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I must be missing something here because I do not understand why my **promise** is not resolving.

I boiled the code down to this simple example:

```
  ...
  console.log("before");
  const promise = second();
  console.log("after");
  console.log(promise);
  ...

async function first() {
  const p1 = await axios.get("https://<url>");
  console.log("first");
  console.log(p1.data);
  return (p1);
}

async function second() {
  const p2 = await first();
  console.log("second");
  console.log(p2.data);
  return (p2);
};
```

Which produces this output in the console:

```
before
after
Promise { <pending> }
first
p1.data
second
p2.data
```

My understanding is that **await** pauses execution until it completes before moving to the next line, but that is clearly not happening.

The initial block completes with a **pending promise**, and then the **awaited** code in the **async** functions executes instead of pausing.

What am I missing to make my code pause and wait until the **await** lines complete with a **resolved promise** before continuing?

Comment: `await` for `second()`

Comment: `async` functions ALWAYS return a Promise that is initially `Pending` ... that's what `async` functions do

Comment: You are calling Async Function without Await that's why it showing Promise pending.
you need to put await before second().

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, all of the following are true:

**A promise**

- Is a value (can be passed around to functions, assigned to variables, and so on)
- Can be in the *resolved*, *rejected*, or *pending* states
- The thing it resolves to is also a value (`1`, `"foo"`, `{}`, ...)
- Can have `.then(...)` callbacks chained to it
- Can be `await`ed

**An `async` function**

- Is a function that *synchronously* returns a promise
- Is a function that *asynchronously* returns the resolved value of that promise

Hopefully this modified example will make it clearer:

```js
// mock axios
const axios = {
    get: url => Promise.resolve({ data: `Some data from ${url}` })
}

const fetchMockData = async () => {
    const val = await axios.get('https://<url>')
    return val
}

const withAsyncAwait = async () => {
    console.log('=== with async/await ===')
    
    const promise = fetchMockData() // not awaited
    console.log('type of promise:', promise.constructor.name)
    const resolved = await promise // here we await it
    console.log('type of resolved:', resolved.constructor.name)
    console.log('data:', resolved.data)
}

// equivalent but with `then` callback
const withThenCallback = () => {
    console.log('=== with then callback ===')
    
    const promise = fetchMockData() // not awaited
    console.log('type of promise:', promise.constructor.name)
    promise.then(resolved => { // resolved thanks to `then`
        console.log('type of resolved:', resolved.constructor.name)
        console.log('data:', resolved.data)
    })
}

setTimeout(withAsyncAwait, 0)
setTimeout(withThenCallback, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

An async function is like a Promise which does not resolve immediately. So you should probably use an immediately invoked anonymous async function:

```
(async()=>{
  console.log("before");
  const promise = await second();
  console.log("after");
  console.log(promise);
})();
```

Comment: _"An async function is a Promise..."_ - It's a function that _returns_ a promise. _"So you should probably use an immediately invoked anonymous async function"_ - How is this going to change anything? The real change is the `await second()` - which only works in an `async` function.

Comment: That is just nomenclature. We can't use 'await' outside an async function. What if we need to call console.log() outside any function on the global scope?

Comment: Is it? `const x = async function() { }; y = new Promise(() => {}); console.log(typeof x, typeof y)` - _"We can't use 'await' outside an async function"_ - That's why you've added the IIFE but that's not the reason why the answer now does what OP asks for. It's the `await`.

Comment: Saying "It's a function that returns a promise." seems quite confusing to me as what follows 'return' inside the function is not necessarily a Promise. 'typeof' doesn't say much. It is just a matter of perspective and choice of words.

Comment: [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function): _"Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise."_

Comment: Fine. I will add the word 'like'.

Comment: This also works, and I'll spend more time on it in the morning because it's late, but I'll sleep much better now that I have a couple solutions to my problems, although I'm going to have to make sure I'm clear on exactly why it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`async function` is not actually an synchronouse function like we think of, its an promise. So you need to handle it like an promise like:

```
console.log("before");
second().then(res => {
  console.log("after");
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: `await`ing it _is_ handling it like a promise. I don't think this answer has anything to do with the question, which is about the `Promise { <pending> }` output in the console.

Comment: This actually does resolve the promise and I can work with this to get what I need, but I've always seen .then() used when dealing directly with promises. I've never seen a .then() clause used with async/await (which may be why I had so much trouble) and curious if there is alternate syntax to accomplish the same thing without the .then().

Comment: @GRW The alternative syntax _is_ `async/await`.  if you have an `async` function, you can `await` it inside another async function, or you can chain `.then`s to it. Conversely, if you have a `then`able, you can `await` it inside an async function to get its result.

Comment: @GRW the newer way is to add `await` infront of `second()` like `await second()`. But you will need to use again an `async` function where you call your second()